# How to prove this theorem on finitely generated $R$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

$R$ is a ring.

> Prove that every finitely generated $R$-module is equal to a sum of cyclic submodules.

Comment: This is by no means a trivial fact.  What facts are you allowed to use and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I guess you are working over a PID. Have you seen Smith normal forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want *direct sum* then the result is generally false (but it holds for $R$ a principal ideal domain).

If you just want *sum*, then it's essentially obvious: if $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$ is a set of generators of the finitely generated (right) $R$-module $M$, then
$$
M=x_1R+x_2R+\dots+x_nR
$$
and each $x_iR$ is a cyclic submodule of $M$.